# Slice rows of selected column according to group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
id   date      num
A    20170301  1
A    20170302  4
A    20170304  2
C    20170302  3
B    20170303  2  
C    20170305  0
B    20170304  5
```

How do I do it so I can get

```
date_A_list = ['20170301','20170302','20170304']
date_B_list = ['20170303','20170304']
date_C_list = ['20170302','20170305']
```

so that every list I check through

```
rng = pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max())
```

and when I pass

```
diff = rng.difference(date_A_list)
```

I get

```
diff = ['20170303']
```

and my dataframe looks like this

```
id   date      num  num_sum    len_diff
A    20170301  1    7          1
A    20170302  4    7          1
A    20170304  2    7          1
B    20170303  2    7          0
B    20170304  5    7          0
C    20170304  3    3          2
C    20170305  0    3          2
```

Comment: What are the datatypes in your initial dataframe?

Comment: for id and date are objects and num is int

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
#convert to datetimes
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')

#groupby + resample by days - get NaNs for missing dates
d1 = df.set_index('date').groupby('id').resample('d')['id'].first()
print (d1)
id  date      
A   2017-03-01      A
    2017-03-02      A
    2017-03-03    NaN
    2017-03-04      A
B   2017-03-03      B
    2017-03-04      B
C   2017-03-02      C
    2017-03-03    NaN
    2017-03-04    NaN
    2017-03-05      C
Name: id, dtype: object

#count NaNs
s = d1.isnull().sum(level=0).astype(int)
print (s)
id
A    1
B    0
C    2
Name: id, dtype: int32
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values('id')
df['num_sum'] = df.groupby('id')['num'].transform('sum')
df['len_diff'] = df['id'].map(s)
print (df)
  id       date  num  num_sum  len_diff
0  A 2017-03-01    1        7         1
1  A 2017-03-02    4        7         1
2  A 2017-03-04    2        7         1
4  B 2017-03-03    2        7         0
6  B 2017-03-04    5        7         0
3  C 2017-03-02    3        3         2
5  C 2017-03-05    0        3         2
```

Another solution with custom function:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')

def f(x):
    rng = pd.date_range(x.min(),x.max())
    return len(rng.difference(x))

df = df.sort_values('id')
df['num_sum'] = df.groupby('id')['num'].transform('sum')
df['len_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(f)
print (df)
  id       date  num  num_sum  len_diff
0  A 2017-03-01    1        7         1
1  A 2017-03-02    4        7         1
2  A 2017-03-04    2        7         1
4  B 2017-03-03    2        7         0
6  B 2017-03-04    5        7         0
3  C 2017-03-02    3        3         2
5  C 2017-03-05    0        3         2
```

Comment: first row 
d = df.groupby('id')['date'].apply(list).to_dict()
where does the list come from?

Comment: it is `apply(list)` - it generate lists per group

Comment: Sorry, I edited my ques, realised what I want is abit different. Can you take a look? Thanks

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone - Thank you, nice weekend ;)